# How to stop velocity.js animation after the animation is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

I am creating a pulsating effect with velocity.js as fallback for IE9, (see box2 for CSS animation ) 
When mouse leaves the box before the animation has finished ( stay until pulse grows than move out ) the pulsating element stays visible. https://jsfiddle.net/02vu80kc/1/

```
        $(".box").hover(function () {

            $(this).find('.effect-holder').velocity({
                scale: [1.2, 0.9],
                opacity: [1, 0]
            }, {
                easing: 'ease-out',
                duration: 800,
                loop: true
            }, {
                queue: false
            }).velocity("reverse");

        }, function () {

            $(this).find('.effect-holder').velocity("stop");


        });
```

How do I stop the animation on mouseout after the effect has finished ?

I am trying to stay away from `.removeAttr('style')` and would like the animation to finish and than stop. Any help is appreciated.

If I use this

```
$(this).find('.effect-holder').velocity('reverse').velocity("stop");
```

and you move the mouse fast the animation begins again and sometimes pauses in between.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Either use `.velocity("finish")` instead of `.velocity("stop")`, or</strike> have a different on and off animation, with *both* animations calling `"stop"` (ie, catch when the mouse moves properly).

Also note that the `{... loop:true ...}` means that the first animation never ends, and hence the `"stop"` will have the "reverse" happen immediately after stopping (call `.velocity("stop", true)` to prevent that)

<strike>edit: Open issue on the `"finish"` bug - https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/495</strike>

edit2: Add simple example:

```
$("box").hover(function() {
    // over
    this.velocity("stop", true).velocity({
        scale: [1.2, 0.9]
    }, {
        duration: 800,
        loop: true
    })
}, function() {
    // out
    this.velocity("stop", true).velocity({
        scale: 0.9
    }, {
        easing: "ease-out",
        duration: 800
    })
});
```

Comment: care to show an example?  finish is pulsating at the end , stop true does not play animation at all

Comment: Just realised that I opened an issue about that finish bug in April - https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/495 - so splitting the hover into a start and stop function would be the only thing to work. If I get the time (and you still want it) then I can put together a quick example, just really busy at work right now!

Comment: sure bud take your time , I am working on other things for now. any time you can please do post an example.